# Pointer manipulation inside function

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have a pointer pointing to memory

```
0x10000000
```

I want to add to it so it traverses down memory, for example:

```
0x10000000 + 5 = 0x10000005
```

How would I do this inside a function? How would I pass in the address that the pointer points to, and inside the function add 5 to it, then after the function's complete, I can use that value?

Comment: How would you do the same kind of thing with, say, an `int`?

Comment: What part of that is your actual problem?  Have you attempted to write your function at all?

Comment: What *type* of pointer is that? How do you know that `ptr + 5` results in a value 5 addresses greater?

Comment: My problem is that I want to do pointer arithmetic inside a function, but after the function's over, I want the pointer to be pointing to the result of that pointer arithmetic. So if the pointer is pointing to 0x10000000 before, after the function runs, it will be pointing to 0x10000005

Comment: If you add 5 to an `int` in a function, how do you get the modified value back to the calling code?  That's how you do it for a pointer, too.  (You have two choices: return the new value, or pass a pointer to the value.  With a pointer as the value, that means a pointer to a pointer is passed.)

Comment: Then you need to pass a pointer to the pointer. (e.g., `void someFunction(int **iPtrVariable)`)

Comment: @SpencerDoak Oh ok, so inside that function I just need to do iPtrVariable += 5? Or should I do *iPtrVariable += 5?

Comment: @JoJo `*iPtrVariable`

Comment: @JoJo, you would need `*iPtrVariable += 5;`. `iPtrVariable` itself points to the pointer to the int variable. As such, if we directly modify `iPtrVariable`, the caller function cannot see the changes we made to it. However, we can modify what `iPtrVariable` points to (which is `*iPtrVariable`) and then the caller function will still have a valid pointer to the pointer that we modified. (Sorry if that explanation seems wordy :P )

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. The function can return the updated pointer.

   ```
   char *f(char *ptr) {
       ptr += 5;
       return ptr;
   }
   ```

The caller then does:

```
    char *p = some_initialization;
    p = f(p);
```

2. The function argument can be a pointer to a pointer, which it indirects through:

   ```
   void f(char **ptr_ptr) {
       *ptr += 5;
   }
   ```

The caller then does:

```
    char *p = some_initialization;
    f(&p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, like what everyone else as said you have to pass the pointer by reference(that is a pointer to a pointer aka double pointer) to the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void IncrementAddress(void **addr)
{
   int offset=5;//give what ever value you want

   *addr = *addr + offset;
    printf("%d\n",*addr);
}  

int main()
{
  char x;// or any other data type like int x or float x etc.
  void *ptr=NULL;
  ptr = &x;

  printf("%d\n",ptr);
  IncrementAddress(&ptr);
  printf("%d\n",ptr);

  return 0;
}
```