# Using a struct directly from pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have a strange question. If, for example, I know that at location

```
0x10000005
```

is a struct that I made. I have a pointer pointing to

```
0x10000000
```

If I use pointer manipulation and make it instead point to 0x10000005, can I use what's at 0x10000005 if I know what struct is there?

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. You show us the code for that situation, and we'll show you how to do it.

Comment: How does this differ from your question from about 5 hours ago: [Pointer manipulation inside function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979898/pointer-manipulation-inside-function)

Comment: That's an odd (literally!) address for a struct.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use pointer manipulation

This is a sketchy statement. On a 32-bit x86 system, a pointer would be 4 bytes. On a 64-bit x86 system, a pointer would be 8 bytes. Sure, I'm willing to bet there's a system where a pointer is 5 bytes, but I'm willing to put my money on a misunderstanding rather than an obscure architecture.

The C11 standard does guarantee this:

> §6.7.2.1
>
> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members ... have
>   addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A
>   pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its
>   initial member ... There may be unnamed padding within a structure
>   object, but not at its beginning.

This means the non-trickery way of getting the address of an object works:

```
struct s* p = &so;
```